# What is Jesse's Judgment Day?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles season 2 episode 17 **"Ourselves Alone"** Derek and Jesse are shooting apples. When they are doing this Derek says that his Judgment Day is **21st April 2011**. After that he asks Jesse what is her Judgment Day is, but she didn't give an answer to Derek.

So what is the reason for Jesse to hide her Judgment day from Derek and why does she keep that as a secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was never explained in or out of universe. There were no clues about when it was, or why she didn't talk about it before the series got canceled.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be so much *what* the actual date was rather than *why* she kept it a secret, though.

Comment: @Napoleon still the same explanation.  Updated. To speculate, Armageddon is traumatic and most people have dead relatives, so I wouldn't expect anyone to be very chatty about it anyway.